# Compare and count consecutive data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make an Excel macro to compare and count data from the same column.

Specifically, I want to count only if the a cell and the cell below the cell both have an absolute value less than 100.

End goal: Say the column below was the data that I have,

```
241.197
96.747
88.325
156
53.666
55.372
-45.667
-207.152
```

I want the macro to return a value of 2. 
It would need to count 
[96.747
88.325]

&

[53.666
55.372
-45.667]

Comment: Glad that you are trying to make a macro, but what have you tried? I could build one from scratch, but if you had a starting point it would help, knowing the columns you are using and where to display the data, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have column A with the data starting at A1

```
sub countTotal

    dim i as integer
    dim sum as double
    dim count as integer

    for i = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        sum = Abs(Range("A" & i).Value) + Abs(Range("A" & i + 1).Value)
        if sum < 100 then count = count + 1
    next

    msgbox count
end sub
```

Not tested. You should see if it counts the last value in your column + the empty one after, if it does, shorten the loop by 1.

Comment: wow this is very helpful! 
but if I were to make the sum = abs(A1) + abs(A2), how would I approach that?
thanks

Comment: and I am trying to make this into a user function and select my range which will be about 80 data points...
Its my first time using macros and I am so lost
Thanks!

Comment: I added the absolutes in the answer. For the range, right now it takes your whole data set. If you want to select your range to apply it on instead, then you need to change the for loop to a For Each (cell) in (selected range), that would need to be another question though! (changing a for to a for each). i suggest you read on for each cell in range first: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/looping_through_a_range_efficiently/ is an OK read

Comment: Also I'm not sure I did the absolute correctly. If you want the absolute of the sum, and not the absolute of the parts, you should remove the abs() around the values and instead add sum = abs(sum) underneath the sum, to take the absolute of the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub countTotal()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sum As Double
Dim count As Integer

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Abs(Range("A" & i).Value) < 100 And Abs(Range("A" & i + 1).Value) < 100 Then
        count = count + 1
    Else
        count = count
    End If
Next

MsgBox count
End Sub
```

Based on your code, this is what I came up with. It performs fine if the data looks like this:

```
120
70
-90
110
80
60
```

In which case the macro returns a value of 2.

The problem is that some of my data looks like this:

```
100
-80
90
70
-180
-190
```

Macro returns a value of 2 because it counts [-80 90] and [90 70]. But I want to make it so that when the absolute value of a consecutive set of data is all less than 100, macro counts it as 1. So ideally instead of returning 2 as the value, the macro should return 1 in this case.

Can you direct me in the right direction?
Thanks!